# POO Propperty getter / setter vs Function (Theory)

Tags: function, class, oop, properties, getter

So if a getter is finally a function, why not use just a function? I guess to enforce using that function to set/get a value any time needed, any other reason?

Answer (score 0):

A getter **is** a function (as far as POO languages I know).

The idea is to delegate the ability to modify or to get an attribute to **only one** function by class, in case of there were special checks to perform before applying the getter or setter.

Answer (score 0):

Properties are used just to improve readability or ease the API, without breaking encapsulation. For example, if you have a `Rectangle` class and you want to increase by 10 the width of an instance, without properties, you would do something like:

```
rect.setWidth(rect.getWidth() + 10)
```

While, using properties, you could just write:

```
rect.width += 10
```

Which is clearer. And because properties are functions, you can do all the checks that you need. Moreover, it doesn't even matter if the width is actually stored in the class; maybe the rectangle is stored as a pair of points (i.e. upper-left and lower-right), but the property would handle it. Additionally, you could write properties that access the same data in different ways: for example, you could have `width`, `height`, `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` properties, and all of them would affect the same internal data of the class, but would make it easier to use and more readable.